# Track the row edit event of ui grid

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I wanted to track the row edit event of the ui grid. I have gone through the gridApi but couldn't got anything related to it.

Can anybody help me with the same.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, try this:

Be sure to set your column's `enableCellEdit: true` in your columnsDefs, then you will want to do something along the lines of...

```
 $scope.gridOptions.onRegisterApi = function(gridApi){
      //set gridApi on scope
      $scope.gridApi = gridApi;
      gridApi.edit.on.afterCellEdit($scope,function(rowEntity, colDef, newValue, oldValue) {

        // do stuff here....

      });
    };
```

You can find more info here http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/201_editable